# is the monopoly reduced/ lowered /shared?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, syntactic-analysis, sentence

If method 1 had a monopoly in imaging domain.
With the arrival of method two, its monopoly is **lowered? reduced?**
Please suggest a suitable word here.

Thank you

Comment: Monopolies are absolute. You can’t have a partial monopoly. The monopoly is *broken* or similar. Its *market share* could be “reduced” or similar, as that is relative, not absolute.

Comment: @DanBron A monopoly could be reduced if, for instance, someone has a monopoly on suppling a commodity in 10 counties, then loses that monopoly status in 1 of those counties.

Comment: Methods don't have monopolies - people do. If the same people control method two, the monopoly hasn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To erode a monopoly", or variants thereof, seem to be in [common usage](https://www.google.com/?q=%22Eroding%20the%20Monopoly%22).

In the sense of being 'gradually destroyed,' it works in your example if Method 1 retains its monopoly in some parts of the imaging domain, but not for the entire domain. If Method 2 competes with Method 1 across the entire domain, Method 1 has lost it's monopoly.

You could also says that "Method 1 [challenges the monopoly](https://www.google.com/?q=%22Challenges%20the%20monopoly%22) of Method 2" if Method 2 still has its monopoly but Method 1 has the potential to change that.

Comment: I find this to be appropraite:
You could also says that "Method 1 challenges the monopoly of Method 2" if Method 2 still has its monopoly but Method 1 has the potential to change that.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Bron says, monopolies are absolute: either there is one or there isn't. (There may admittedly be temporal and regional restrictions involved in the use of the term. 'InflationCo had a monopoly in the eighties in Elbonia on fuzzgees.') This is not to say that there may be a near-monopoly or 'virtual monopoly', so JeffUK's suggestion makes sense, though the language would probably not satisfy a purist. But then we do speak of container A being more full than container B, short for 'more nearly full'.

But there is a standard verb to use here:

> **break a monopoly**
>
> - *Head teachers were permitted to recruit their own staff and new governors were brought in to break the monopoly of local authority
>   control.* [Times, Sunday Times]
> - Does it matter if new players - tech gazillionaires and governments - break the monopoly enjoyed for centuries by professional journalists? [Times, Sunday Times]
> - *Regulations enacted in 1828 attempted to break the monopoly of the missions and also made land grants easier to obtain.*  [Wikipedia ...
>   History of the San Fernando Valley]
> - *In an attempt to break this monopoly, the government proposed allowing mobile fast food vans to operate at the areas, though this
>   idea has not come about.* [Wikipedia ... Motorway service area]
> - *The internet was supposed to be the great leveller, breaking the monopoly of elites on information and creating a new democratic
>   impulse.* [Times, Sunday Times]

[[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break-a-monopoly)]